# how to get the selected connection node object of VS Server Explorer window DDEX

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I'm adding some options for the Connection Node in the server explorer for my VS extension. For one of the menu options that I have added I need to get the connection string of the very selected connection, So I have tried this by adding some code in the BeforeQueryStatus event and also in the command handler method. But looks like I'm missing something since every time I want to get an Instance of the DataViewHierarchyAccessor I always get a null value. Although if I do the same thing but in a lower level node works fine. I have used the following code with no luck:

IVsDataExplorerNodeSelection nodeSelection = (IVsDataExplorerNodeSelection)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(IVsDataExplorerNodeSelection));

IVsUIHierarchy hierarchy = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(hierarchyPtr, typeof(IVsUIHierarchy)) as IVsUIHierarchy;

Has anybody done something similar for the Connection Node of the Server Explorer Window?

Update:

Looks like I got some progress on this, I just tried this:

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 _applicationObject = GetDTE2();
UIHierarchy uih = _applicationObject.ToolWindows.GetToolWindow("Server Explorer") as UIHierarchy;
Array selectedItems = (Array)uih.SelectedItems;
if (null != selectedItems)
    {
        foreach (UIHierarchyItem selItem in selectedItems)
        {
            SelectedItem prjItem = selItem.Object as EnvDTE.SelectedItem;
            string name = prjItem.Name;
        }
    }
```

Now my question is if there's a better type to cast the list of selectedItems? instead of EnvDTE.SelectedItem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking my question as answered since the code that I posted did the trick.

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 _applicationObject = GetDTE2();
UIHierarchy uih = _applicationObject.ToolWindows.GetToolWindow("Server Explorer") as UIHierarchy;
Array selectedItems = (Array)uih.SelectedItems;
if (null != selectedItems)
{
    foreach (UIHierarchyItem selItem in selectedItems)
    {
        SelectedItem prjItem = selItem.Object as EnvDTE.SelectedItem;
        string name = prjItem.Name;
    }
}
```