# Visual Studio extension, get information about node in server explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I have built a Visual Studio extension which adds a menu item to the context menu of the "Tables" node and each child node in the Server Explorers data connections section.

[image]

I've wired up the menu item so the BeforeQueryStatus  event fires before the menu appears so I can dynamically control the state of the menu item, making it enabled/disabled or choosing whether the menu item should appear at all.

In both the BeforeQueryStatus event and the invoke handler I need to access information about the object that the selected node represents.  I need to know the Connection String property of the actual data connection, which is represented in the "Tables" parent node.

[image: Data connection properties]

If the selected node is a table node (child of "Tables") I also need to know the table name and schema that the node is representing.

I've tried looking at various objects and can't seem to locate what I'm after.  Any help appreciated.  Here is my starting point:

```
private void Mnu_BeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleMenuCommand mnu = (OleMenuCommand)sender;
    EnvDTE.DTE service = (EnvDTE.DTE)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));

    EnvDTE.ContextAttributes ctx = service.ContextAttributes;
    EnvDTE.Window w = service.ActiveWindow;
    //EnvDTE.Properties p = service.Properties.;
    EnvDTE.SelectedItems si = service.SelectedItems;

    EnvDTE.ProjectItem pi = w.ProjectItem; //null
    var selection = w.Selection; //null

    var obj = w.Object;
    var objk = w.ObjectKind; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could get all connections via IVsDataExplorerConnectionManager, and the following code for your reference.

```
IVsDataExplorerConnectionManager connectionManager = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IVsDataExplorerConnectionManager)) as IVsDataExplorerConnectionManager;
            IDictionary<string, IVsDataExplorerConnection> connections = connectionManager.Connections;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IVsDataExplorerConnection> connection in connections)
            {

                if(connection.Key == "youconnectionkey")
                { 
                    string connstr = connection.Value.Connection.DisplayConnectionString;
                    string NodeText = connection.Value.DisplayName;
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    DataTable schema = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
                    List<string> TableNames = new List<string>();
                    foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
                    {
                        TableNames.Add(row[2].ToString());
                    }
                }


                }
            }
```

In addition, please add the following reference.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Services;
```

Comment: This is great!  I wonder then how I can correlate a given connection in the connection manager with a node in the server explorer.  Because My event is firing when the user displays the popup menu, so I need to find the connection that correlates to the node the user right clicked on.

Comment: You could use UIHierarchy.SelectedItems to get the connection information that user right clicked on. Similar code, you could refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541438/how-to-get-the-selected-connection-node-object-of-vs-server-explorer-window-ddex