# Visual Studio extension to find which database has been selected in the Server Explorer

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-extensions, server-explorer

I'm new to creating Visual Studio Extensions.

I wanted to create an extension in Visual Studio 2017 that shows the name and the details (server name, username, password) of the database that the user connects from the Server Explorer.

I explored that the GUID of Server Explorer is **guid_SE_MenuGroup**. But I could not figure out how to determine the name of the database that the user selects.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you could get the select connection string of the selected connection, does it mean that you could get the database name?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541438/how-to-get-the-selected-connection-node-object-of-vs-server-explorer-window-ddex

Comment: Will the select connection string have the credentials of that database selected in the Server Explorer?